How to simplify a sum involving combination numbers?
Can you please show me how to simplify $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1-s} \binom{n-1-s}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+s+1}?$$
I know the result is $$\frac{s! (n-1-s)!}{n!}$$ (for calculating Shapley value), but just want to know how to simplify.

Using the fact that $\dfrac{1}{k+s+1} = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+s}\,dx$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1-s} \dbinom{n-1-s}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+s+1} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1-s} \binom{n-1-s}{k}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+s}\,dx
\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}x^s\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1-s} \binom{n-1-s}{k}(-1)^kx^{k}\right]\,dx
\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}x^s(1-x)^{n-1-s}\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{s!(n-1-s)!}{n!}
\end{align*}$$
where we have used the integral for the beta function $\displaystyle\int_0^{1}x^a(1-x)^b\,dx = \dfrac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!}$.

Greetings. Thank you so much for the beautiful proof. This is a result given by Nobel Laureate Lloyd Stowell Shapley in his seminal paper on the Shapley value, where he did not   provide a proof. Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays.
